# How to fix 'Object is Possibly null' error in reactive Form Validation?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

In my .ts file , i have set null as default value for my reactive form and validated with required attribute in reactive form as below :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-rective-forms',
  templateUrl: './rective-forms.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./rective-forms.component.css']
})
export class RectiveFormsComponent implements OnInit {

genders = ['Male' , 'Female'];

  signUpForm!: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.signUpForm = new FormGroup ( {                                                      // empty Reactive Form Created 
      'username' : new FormControl( null ,Validators.required) ,                               // Adding username input field with initial value 'null'.
       'email' : new FormControl(null , [Validators.required , Validators.email] ),                                   // Adding email input field with initial value 'null'.
       'gender' : new FormControl('Male')                                               // Adding gender radio button with default value as 'Male'.
     } );  

  }

onSubmit(){
  console.log(" Form Submitted ! ");
  console.log(this.signUpForm);
  
  
}
```

In my HTML, I have tried to display the message if the field is not valid using the get method. But, It shows an error that denotes 'Object Possibly null'. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I have imported ReactiveFormsModule correctly. Other things work perfectly except this one. Please help me to fix this. Thank you.

```
 <input type="text"
               id="username"
               formControlName="username"
                class="form-control"
                >

                <span 
                *ngIf="!signUpForm.get('username').valid && signUpForm.get('username').touched"
                class="help-block"
                > Enter User Name ! </span>
```

Comment: The objects `signUpForm.get('username')` and `signUpForm.get('username')` can be null. Use the safe navigation operator ?: `signUpForm?.get('username')?.valid` and `signUpForm?.get('username')?.touched`.

Answer (score 0):

at first you should inject FormBuilder into constructor  like below code :

> private fb: FormBuilder,

and then you can create form Group like this code:

> this.signUpForm = this.fb.group({
> username: [null, [Validators.required]],
> ...
> } );

and in Html form you should write below Code :

```
<form class="text-center" [formGroup]="signUpForm" (ngSubmit)="login()">
 <div class="form-group my-3">
      <div class="form-floating">
        <input type="text" class="form-control text-right" id="floatingusername" formControlName="username"
          placeholder="username">
        <label for="floatingusername">username</label>
      </div>
      <small class="form-text text-right text-danger"
        *ngIf="loginForm.get('username').hasError('required') && loginForm.get('username').touched">
       username is required
      </small>
    </div>
```